# Launch continuous windows of command prompt with an echo message

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I want a batch file that will launch a continuous loop of cmd with and echo message

I can do it without echo with this code

```
@echo off
:1
start
GOTO 1
```

but all I want is that the every opened cmd window should give an echo message like "hello".

Comment: That sounds malicious.  You'll crash someone's PC with never-ending windows.

Comment: this is just for educational and learning purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here This Might Do It For You. (Remove The Spaces Between The Codes)

@echo off

echo (Your Message Here)

start (batfilename).bat

(batfilename).bat